# Text appear in zoom in effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can we show text in zoom in effect. I saw it on one travel site. I did google but cant find this kind of effect. I just want little hint what kind of effect is this. I red about easing but did not find the same effect. I have attached screenshot for the same. Here is link of that website http://cleartrip.com/flights?ui=v3. The effect is on payment page [image]

Comment: Can you add screen before zoom?

Comment: There is no green box at starting it will after you accept condition on website. you have to do a search for effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so when you do something to make the section appear, the button within it animates from nothing to 100% size from its center point. So basically what you are asking is how to make something grow from 0% to 100% via animation. There's probably a totally javascript way but I personally would use css animation for this.

Suppose you are adding a class to the parent div to reveal a section of content (in the example you linked to it is revealing a section of the order form) all you need to do is in the css add an animation to the button that is triggered when the section gets a class added. In my example below I'm calling the section 'page' and assuming you're adding a class of 'active' to reveal it - obviously these could be anything you like:
Html:

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="animated_button">Look at me</div>
  [other content that you don't want to animate]
</div>
```

Css:

```
.page{
  display:none;  
}
.active{
  display:block;
}

.animated_button{
  [styling for how you want your button to look]
}

.active .animated_button{ 
  animation: growUp 0.4s;
}

@keyframes growUp {
  0%   { transform:scale(0); }
  100% { transform:scale(1); }
}
```

Note that you may need to add vendor-prefixes for the transforms.
Here is a codePen - there's a few extra styles and stuff in there just to show an example of how it works:
http://codepen.io/chrisboon27/pen/weJmL

Comment: No problem. CSS animations are really cool, there's a lot you can achieve with them. CSS-tricks has a useful introductory if you want to learn more, and has a list of all the prefixes you need for various browsers: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/